How do I fix this error? PLEASE HELP ME
[2024-07-18T18:51:20.140305625Z ERROR solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: panic program="validator" thread="main" one=1i message="panicked at /var/lib/buildkite-agent/builds/kong-1/solana-labs/solana-secondary/runtime/src/snapshot_bank_utils.rs:374:9:
    Snapshot bank for slot 283226406 failed to verify" location="/var/lib/buildkite-agent/builds/kong-1/solana-labs/solana-secondary/runtime/src/snapshot_bank_utils.rs:374:9" version="1.17.25 (src:d0ed878d; feat:3580551090, client:SolanaLabs)"

is the error I got.
If you need any other information please say so!

Upgrade to the latest recommended Solana version and wipe Ledger and accounts directories before starting.
